# Building dependent relationships in Rails - is there a better pattern than after_create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a model that requires a ton of dependencies... it looks something like this:

```
after_create :create_dependencies

def create_dependencies
  create_foo
  create_bar
  create_baz
  # ...
end
```

This is really polluting my model class with a bunch of this nonsense. Is there another way I can go about this? I would love to use a form object or something like that, but I want to ensure all of these objects come with their dependent relationships no matter what, even when created through command line, in a test suite, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My first reaction was to create a Form object like you mentioned ([as described by Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects)). However you're right that if you save a model directly none of the dependencies will be created.

One approach you could take is to refactor the dependency creation out into a separate class:

```
# lib/my_model_dependency_creator.rb
class MyModelDependencyCreator
  def initialize(my_model)
    @my_model = my_model
  end

  def create_dependencies
    create_foo
    create_bar
    # etc
  end

  private
  def create_foo
    # create dependency associated with @my_model
  end

  def create_bar
  end
end
```

Then in your model class:

```
...
after_create :create_dependencies
def create_dependencies
  MyModelDependencyCreator.new(self).create_dependencies
end
```

Comment: Why not observer? This is basically what an observer does

Answer (score 0):

First, any thought about observers?

Second, I guess it's not that hard to extract the code.

```
#include this module in your model
module AutoSaveDependency
  def auto_save_dependencies *deps
    @@auto_save_dependencies = deps
  end

  def auto_save
    @@auto_save_dependencies.each {|dep| send "create_#{dep}" }
  end

  def self.included(model)
    model.send :after_create, :auto_save
  end
end
```

So in your model, you just include this module, and write `auto_save_dependencies :foo, :bar, ...`

It could be more complicated but I think it's doable